# unresolved external symbol в C++ на пустом месте

Tags: c++

В коде не существует ничего под именнем `_DXGI_DEBUG_ALL` или в чего то в этом духе, существует только `DXGI_DEBUG_ALL` (без нижнего подчеркивания). При линковке в Visual Studio 2019, выдает:

```
LNK2001 | unresolved external symbol _DXGI_DEBUG_ALL | DxgiInfoManager.obj | Line: 1
LNK2120 | 1 unresolved externals                     | DxgiInfoManager.obj | Line: 1
```

И вот что ты не поделаешь, а оно всеравно ругаеться на подчеркивание!

КОД DxgiInfoManager.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Win.h"
#include <wrl.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <dxgidebug.h>

class DxgiInfoManager
{
public:
    DxgiInfoManager();
    ~DxgiInfoManager();
    DxgiInfoManager(const DxgiInfoManager&) = delete;
    DxgiInfoManager& operator=(const DxgiInfoManager&) = delete;
    void Set() noexcept;
    std::vector<std::string> GetMesssages() const;
private:
    unsigned long long next = 0u;
    struct IDXGIInfoQueue* pDxgiInfoQueue = nullptr;
};
```

КОД DxgiInfoManager.cpp:

```cpp
#include "DxgiInfoManager.h"
#include "Window.h"
#include "Graphics.h"
#include <dxgidebug.h>
#include <memory>
#include <dxgidebug.h>

#define GFX_THROW_NOINFO(hrcall) if( FAILED( hr = (hrcall) ) ) throw Graphics::HrException( __LINE__,__FILE__,hr )

DxgiInfoManager::DxgiInfoManager()
{
    // define function signature of DXGIGetDebugInterface
    typedef HRESULT(WINAPI * DXGIGetDebugInterface)(REFIID, void**);

    // load the dll that contains the function DXGIGetDebugInterface
    const auto hModDxgiDebug = LoadLibraryEx("dxgidebug.dll", nullptr, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR);
    if (hModDxgiDebug == nullptr)
    {
        throw WND_LAST_EXCEPT();
    }

    // get address of DXGIGetDebugInterface
    const auto DxgiGetDebugInterface = reinterpret_cast<DXGIGetDebugInterface>(
        reinterpret_cast<void*>(GetProcAddress( hModDxgiDebug, "DXGIGetDebugInterface" ))
    );
    if (DxgiGetDebugInterface == nullptr)
    {
        throw WND_LAST_EXCEPT();
    }

    HRESULT hr;
    GFX_THROW_NOINFO(DxgiGetDebugInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIInfoQueue), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pDxgiInfoQueue)));
}

DxgiInfoManager::~DxgiInfoManager()
{

}

void DxgiInfoManager::Set() noexcept
{
    // set the index (next) so that the next all to GetMessage()
    // will only get errors generated after this all
    next = pDxgiInfoQueue->GetNumStoredMessages(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL);
}

std::vector<std::string> DxgiInfoManager::GetMesssages() const
{
    std::vector<std::string> messages;
    const auto end = pDxgiInfoQueue->GetNumStoredMessages(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL);
    for (auto i = next; i < end; i++)
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        SIZE_T messageLength;

        // get the size of a messsage i in bytes

        GFX_THROW_NOINFO(pDxgiInfoQueue->GetMessage(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, i, nullptr, &messageLength));

        // alocate memory for message

        auto bytes = std::make_unique<byte[]>(messageLength);
        auto pMessage = reinterpret_cast<DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_MESSAGE*>(bytes.get());

        // get the message and push its description into vector

        GFX_THROW_NOINFO(pDxgiInfoQueue->GetMessage(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, i, pMessage, &messageLength));
        messages.emplace_back(pMessage->pDescription);
    }
    return messages;
}
```

Если потребуеться дополнительная информация, постараюсь добавить как можно скорее :)

Comment: Так в где этот `DXGI_DEBUG_ALL` определен?

Comment: У вас в .cpp, `dxgidebug.h` два раза дублируется + в заголовочном он тоже есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В C/C++ x86 глобальные переменные и "C"-функции, при трансляции в ассемблер, получают префикс "_" . У вас переменная DXGI_DEBUG_ALL видимо описана, как extern, но нигде не размещена.

То есть переменную DXGI_DEBUG_ALL надо указать в каком-то cpp файле без `extern`

Comment: Это мой первый раз когда я работаю с какими либо библиотеками, так что немогли бы сказать как именно указать это переменную без extern. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: если у вас в test.h описано `extern int test;`, то в test.cpp надо написать `int test;` - и это будет физическое размещение переменной `test`

Comment: Проблема в том, что DXGI_DEBUG_ALL подключена с помощью #include <dxgidebug.h> и LoadLibraryEx(). Если я правильно вас понял, то мне надо просто обьявить DXGI_DEBUG_ALL самостоятельно?

Comment: а, так это сторонняя библиотека, тогда для неё должен быть какой-то *.lib и его надо указать в проекте, а не пользоваться `LoadLibraryEx`, тогда система при загрузке вашего exe сама будет искать dll

Comment: Хмм, просто я использую LoadLibraryEx только потому, что он возвращает объект типа HMODULE который используеться далее для получения DxgiDebugInterface. Так-же, я немогу найти .lib файл... Есть только файл заголовка, а именно .h

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Два дня сидел, а помогло банальное объявление const GUID DXGI_DEBUG_ALL в DxgiInfoManager.h. Вот какова порой жизнь не справедлива!

Comment: `const GUID DXGI_DEBUG_ALL` надо перенести в cpp файл, иначе если вы укажете `DxgiInfoManager.h` в двух и более cpp, то будет "multiple definition of linker error"

Comment: Что вы такое пишете? Этот символ относится к библиотеке DXGI, нельзя его определять у себя. Он уже определён там, где следует, см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `dxguid.lib` в список библиотек для линковки.